# understanding some source code

Tags: c, windows

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I am reviewing someones source code, and I have come across this.

I have this declaration and definition that I don't understand what it does. I know that the static means that it will not be exported out of the file.

```
static SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_win_status_handle = NULL;
```

Because it is set to NULL it looks like a pointer. SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE isnt' defined anywhere else. Only this file.

It is being used like this, is this comparing if g_win_status_handle is equal to NULL after SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE is casted to 0 or NULL:

```
if(g_win_status_handle == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0) {
    /* do something */
}
```

And like this:

```
if(!SetServiceStatus(g_win_status_handle, &g_win_status)) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Many thanks if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: `gcc -E` shows you preprocessor output. You'll find that `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is, in fact, defined.

Comment: *A handle to a service status value. For more information, see SCM Handles.
This type is declared in WinSvc.h as follows:
typedef HANDLE SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;* - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx. In case you're wondering, `HANDLE` is `void *`.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks, That website explained everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made small program

```
#include<stdio.h>

static SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_win_status_handle = NULL;
int main()
{
if(g_win_status_handle == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0) {
        printf("ksdfbhdejkfb");
}
return 0;
}
```

compiled on `gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)`

with c89 flags, like

```
gcc -std=c89 temp.c
```

its giving error

```
temp.c:3:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘g_win_status_handle’
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:6:4: error: ‘g_win_status_handle’ undeclared (first use in this function)
temp.c:6:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
temp.c:6:28: error: ‘SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
temp.c:6:50: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

Here it is obvious that SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE must be defined some where.. if not defined then how your code is going to even compile?

May be it will be defined in some header file..

---

**Updated answer from comments**

`SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is defined in `windows.h` and its going to include.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Include `<windows.h>` (as one might guess from the link in my comment) and it should compile.

Comment: @chris he is using gcc so i might thought that he is working in linux. perhaps windows dont have gcc..people use cygwin for that in windows. I dont have windows machine if you have then try to compile that...

Comment: I use GCC all the time on Windows (via MinGW), but the one I have is set up for C++ and annoying to change to C and back. It does compile in C++, however.

Comment: oh if that compiles in c++ then it must be working in c also.!! Question should have windows tag..!!!

Comment: Your correct it was defined in the a windows header file. Normally I don't work with windows, and thought he was doing something else with that. I should have looked more closely. Thanks